# Generic type casting method (.Net)

Tags: c#, .net, types

I'm trying to create a generic method to cast an object, but can't seem to crack that chestnut. (It's Friday 3pm, been a long week)

Ok, so I have this scenario:

```
// We have a value (which .net sets as a double by default)
object obj = 1.0;

// We have the target type as a string, which could be anything:
// say string sometType = "System.Decimal"
Type type = Type.GetType(someType);

// I need a generic way of casting this
object castedObj = (xxx) obj;
```

How can I cast that object generically without creating an endless number of if-else-staments?

Comment: Do you want to type cast it to the type represented by the `type` variable?
How would you declare the castedObj? I.e what type would you give it? There's no point typecasting if you store it as an object anyway...

Comment: You cannot cast a boxed int to any struct type other than int (or int?) (See http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx for details.) If you need to do this then you need to use something other than a cast.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) method, if the types you use implement [IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx) (all primitive types do).

```
    Convert.ChangeType(value, targetType);
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype%28lightweight%29.aspx) method, I think it will meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast it to a type you specify dynamically.

You may consider using [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(VS.80).aspx) instead, but I would need more code to see how it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
    Type underlyingType = Type.GetType(someType);


    if (underlyingType.IsGenericType && underlyingType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof (Nullable<>)))
    {
        var converter = new NullableConverter(underlyingType);
        underlyingType = converter.UnderlyingType;
    }

    // Try changing to Guid  
    if (underlyingType == typeof (Guid))
    {
        return new Guid(value.ToString());
    }
    return Convert.ChangeType(value, underlyingType);
```

Kudos to [Monsters Go My.net](http://monstersgotmy.net/post/QueryString-Candy-Could-Rot-Your-Teeth.aspx) for the change type function